# Fast merge of very many small matlab matrices

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, merge

I need to merge around 50 million small Matlab matrices. Using a script like the below seems never to finish. Is there a faster way? I'd be willing to try a non-Matlab Route if that were faster.

```
main_data_a = zeros(10000000, 3);
main_data_b = zeros(10000000, 3);
main_data_c = ones(10000000, 1);
for i=1:1:10000000
    try
        to_load=sprintf('data/output%d.mat',i);
        load(to_load);
    catch

    end;
    if sum(a) ~= 0 
        main_data_a(i,:) = a;
        main_data_b(i,:) = b;
        main_data_c(i,:) = c;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you preallocate `main_data`? Growing it at every iteration is going to be very expensive!

Comment: Yes, good point, -- have edited it to reflect that.

Comment: The other thing you could do is use the transposed of those arrays. Filling in a column should be faster than filling in a row. Other than that, just be patient. Next time save your data in a different way. ;)

Comment: Give a try to [parfor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html). It will speed up based on number of available cores on your machine.

Comment: @TusharNakini Does parfor preserve the ordering?

Comment: When number of file is very large changing [the type of filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-is-the-most-high-performance-linux-filesystem-for-storing-a-lot-of-small-fi) can improve the speed.

Comment: @dothyphendot, yes it will preserve the order because `i` works as an identifier for both what to load and the location in the matrix. Though e.g output10.mat is not necessarily loaded before output12.mat.

Comment: Have you profiled this (for a smaller range of `i` values if the runtime is unreasonable otherwise)? If the `load` takes up most of the time, I don't see what else you could do - although you could try assigning the `load` result to a variable (giving you a struct) and accessing the data as `myvar.a`, `myvar.b`, etc, just in case that's quicker.

Comment: @rahnema1 changing the file system would probably be very effective but is not an option.

Comment: @TusharNakini parfor seems like it might be the best option. In lieu of any alternatives if one of you wants to write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example showing "parfor" usage.

```
disp('Using for-loop')
tmpData = zeros(100000,1);
tic
for i = 1:length(tmpData)
    tmpData(i) = max(max(eig(i*ones(100,100))));   % Some operation
end
toc

disp('Using parfor-loop')
tic
parfor (i = 1:length(tmpData))
    tmpData(i) = max(max(eig(i*ones(100,100))));   % Some operation
end
toc
```

The above code resulted in the following timings on my machine.

```
Using for-loop
Elapsed time is 32.792182 seconds.
Using parfor-loop
Elapsed time is 7.673821 seconds.
```

However, if some simple calculations are carried out inside the for (or parfor) loop body then "for-loop" runs faster than "parfor". For example, if you replace `tmpData(i) = max(max(eig(i*ones(100,100))));` with `tmpData(i) = i;` then you could see that for-loop performs better.